What value should I use for the Impedance trace to copper?
I am designing a PCB with a USB Type-C connector. The USB requires a differential pair for high-speed data signals, and I need to calculate the trace width for these differential pair traces. To do this, I decided to use the JLCPCB Impedance Calculator because I order my PCBs from JLCPCB, and their tool provides the trace dimensions and stack-up based on the parameters I input. Here's how I configured the tool:
Impedance: Set to 90 Ω, as this is the standard for USB differential pairs.
Type: Chose Coplanar Differential Pair since the USB differential pair is routed with adjacent ground copper fills for better impedance control.
Signal Layer: Selected L1 because the differential pair is on the top outer layer of the PCB.
Top Reference: Left blank because there is no reference plane above the traces; the traces are on the outermost layer.
Bottom Reference: Set to L2, as this layer is configured as the ground plane.
Trace Width: Left blank, as this value is calculated automatically by the JLCPCB tool based on the other inputs and the required impedance.
Trace Spacing: Set to 0.2000 mm, as it is the clearance between the two traces in the differential pair. JLCPCB supports a minimum clearance of 0.1 mm, but I chose this value to ensure sufficient spacing while maintaining good impedance matching.
Impedance Trace to Copper: Left at the default value of 0.2032 mm (8 mils) because I’m unsure of the exact value to use in my design.
My Question:
How should I choose the Impedance Trace to Copper value (which represents the conductor-to-ground gap in a coplanar waveguide configuration) based on the layout of the PCB? Specifically, how do I determine the appropriate lateral distance between the signal traces and the surrounding ground copper (or any other nearby copper features) to ensure accurate impedance control?
The layout:

The JLCPCB Impedance Calculator:

User guide to the JLCPCB Impedance Calculator:


What is your calculated trace width with your current inputs?

@ThePhoton the trace width calculated by JLCPCB is 0.1547 mm.

The trace-to-copper distance isn't critical here. If you reduce it, then the required trace width will be slightly reduced. Which is probably not desirable because narrower traces are harder to keep in tolerance (due to over-etching and etch profile effects being greater relative to the nominal trace width).
Increasing the trace-to-copper distance might allow you to slightly increase the trace width, but the effect will probably be very small because you have only 0.1 mm dielectric thickness, meaning that capacitance between the traces and the L2 reference plane will be much greater than between the traces and the coplanar ground.
These traces are acting mostly as microstrip lines, with only a small adjustment to the geometry required due to capacitance with the coplanar ground.

So in this case can I leave the Impedance Trace to Copper value at the default 0.2032 mm?

@Robert, yes. Try adjusting it in the calculator and see how much difference it makes in the calculated trace width...it will be very small.

Thank you very much!
